# How can I link to an Android app from an email without the need of gmail?

Tags: android, html, email, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to link to my App (made with Xamarin Android) from an email. This works. When I open the link in gmail, the app is opened indeed. However, when using another well known mail client (such as Outlook or Android Email) the situation is different. It tries to browse to the link instead of opening my app.

Here is my html (of the mail):

```
    <a href="http://testje1.mywebdomain.net" style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;background-color:#5bc0de;border-color:#46b8da;display:inline-block;padding:6px 12px;margin-bottom:0;font-size:14px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.42857143;text-align:center;white-space:nowrap;vertical-align:middle;-ms-touch-action:manipulation;touch-action:manipulation;cursor:pointer;-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none;background-image:none;border:1px solid transparent;border-radius:4px"

  role="button">HTTP</a>
<a href="ftp://testje2.mywebdomain.net" style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;background-color:#5bc0de;border-color:#46b8da;display:inline-block;padding:6px 12px;margin-bottom:0;font-size:14px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.42857143;text-align:center;white-space:nowrap;vertical-align:middle;-ms-touch-action:manipulation;touch-action:manipulation;cursor:pointer;-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none;background-image:none;border:1px solid transparent;border-radius:4px"

  role="button">FTP</a>
<a href="doe://testje3.mywebdomain.net" style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;background-color:#5bc0de;border-color:#46b8da;display:inline-block;padding:6px 12px;margin-bottom:0;font-size:14px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.42857143;text-align:center;white-space:nowrap;vertical-align:middle;-ms-touch-action:manipulation;touch-action:manipulation;cursor:pointer;-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none;background-image:none;border:1px solid transparent;border-radius:4px"

  role="button">doe</a>
```

In gmail, the "ftp" link directly links to my app. The "http" link asks if my browser needs to be opened or my app. The "doe" link does not work (which is no problem).

Here is my C# code with intent filters:

```
[Activity(Label = "MultiLinks", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
DataScheme = "http",
DataHost = "testje1.mywebdomain.net",
Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault })]
public class MainActivity : Activity
```

---

```
[Activity(Label = "SecondActivity")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
DataScheme = "ftp",
DataHost = "testje2.mywebdomain.net",
Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault })]
public class SecondActivity : Activity
```

---

```
[Activity(Label = "ThirdActivity")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
DataScheme = "doe",
DataHost = "testje3.mywebdomain.net",
Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault })]
public class ThirdActivity : Activity
```

---

How can I link to my app from an email and make it work in another email app than Gmail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, you need to add the `Browsable` `Category` to your `IntentFilter` if you want a webbrowser to be able to launch your app:

https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html#adding-filters

> Include the BROWSABLE category. The BROWSABLE category is required in
>   order for the intent filter to be accessible from a web browser.
>   Without it, clicking a link in a browser cannot resolve to your app.
>   The DEFAULT category is optional, but recommended. Without this
>   category, the activity can be started only with an explicit intent,
>   using your app component name.

Hence your categories should look like:

```
Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault,
     Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable }
```

So when another client launches a web browser, the web browser should be able to find out that the link actually belongs to an installed app.

The Chrome browser also supports special url's which can launch an `Intent` directly or show the play store page if the `Intent` is not present on the device.

It could look like:

```
intent://myApp/#Intent;scheme=myScheme;package=my.awesome.package.name;S.browser_fallback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.com;end
```

More about that here: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Comment: Indeed browsable category is needed and solves the problem. The chrome Android Intents are not useful. The links do work in the Android E-mail app and the outlook app but not in the Gmail App. FTP links are far more effective. If the app is available, the app is opened without asking the user for opening the browser instead. If this should be asked, a http link is good.